# Find column name in list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

I'm sorry if this is similar to other questions asked but I'd like to isolate the dataframes within a list of dataframes that include a certain column name. How would I search for the `example` elements that contain the column name `b`?

Ideally I'd like to use an elegant solution like map and purrr!

```
example <- list(data.frame(a = NA, b = NA),
                data.frame(a = NA, c = NA),
                data.frame(b = NA, d = NA))
```

## Desired Output

```
1 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
which(sapply(example, function(x) any(names(x) == "b")))

[1] 1 3
```

One `purrr` option could be:

```
which(map_lgl(example, ~ any(names(.) == "b")))
```

Comment: I wanted a more purrr/tidyverse approach since this is kind of hard to read, but it gets the job done!

Comment: Provided also a `purrr` approach, although I think that the `base R` possibility is better :)